# Uploading Image to AWS from Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, file-upload, image-uploading

How can I upload the image/file from Android to AWS S3. I **already have the URL** provided by the backend developer. He said me to use the **"PUT"** request on this URL and image will be uploaded.

I tried from Postman, it is working fine there. But I need to know, how can I upload image to that URL from Android, because there is no parameter or anything the URL requires.

**How can I directly upload the image/file to this URL from android.**

***URL (where I need to upload):***

https://jpp-internal-test.s3.amazonaws.com/temp/43a40cb4d2c82a5ea4ae286b16ae3872bac.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAXZKKX3KKZCY7KOYZ%2F20190523%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190523T071047Z&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Signature=2faec030f08b9061d0ccd22ea5828f6c88d08eb2c388bd4a188eb512ee92e1b1&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-acl&x-amz-acl=public-read

Answer (score 1):

You can also use AWS Amplify framework. The Storage related documentation is here: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/storage which will guide you through provisioning S3 bucket and installing Amplify. I'd suggest going over that documentation even if you have your own bucket. If you want to use an existing S3 bucket, it will be clearer how to add it to the `amplifyconfiguration.json` to configure the Amplify Storage plugin.

The Java code will then look like this:

```
Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
            "myUploadedFileName.txt",
            sampleFile.getAbsolutePath(),
            new ResultListener<StorageUploadFileResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(StorageUploadFileResult result) {
                   Log.i("StorageQuickStart", "Successfully uploaded: " + result.getKey());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable error) {
                    Log.e("StorageQuickstart", "Upload error.", error);
                }
            }
    );
```